# Zend: Which Class/Controller should i access from out of the module?

Tags: zend-framework, module

I have a running application and added my first module. Everthing works fine. Now i want want to use my module in the existing application.

I have the following folders:

```
application
- classes
- configs
- controllers
- ....
- modules
   - discount
     - configs
     - controllers
     - layouts
     - models
     - plugins
     - views
- ....
- views
```

In an existing class under application/class i want to use some functions that belong to the module.

Now my questions: 
1) Where should i store these functions i want to access from outside?
2) How can i access these from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your module is already registered with your application, for example in `application/configs/application.ini`, like so:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

After that, the files belonging to your module can be accessed anywhere you like, as they are now part of your application. So for example, in `application/controllers/IndexController.php` you could simply do:

```
$myModel = new Discount_Model_MyModel();
```